# How can I use my custom wordpress theme on two websites?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I've built a custom wordpress theme for a website, and now I want to apply the same theme to another site.

I could easily do this by duplicating the website and changing the content, but then subsequent changes to the theme won't be carried over (and I foresee a lot of changes that will need to be made in the future). I need a way to keep the theme synchronised between website.

Ideally, I will be able to change the theme on either site and apply the changes to the other, but if the changes have to be made on one "main" website that's OK too.

Comment: While I can advise against some methods, there is no correct way to do this, e.g. a manual sync vs git vs rsync on a cron job vs composer etc etc, you need to be able to mark something as the correct canonical answer. Not just for your specific use case, but for everyone, that when you have this problem **this** is what you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Use multisite, so you have a centralized theme and any number of wordpress sites you want.
2. Submit your theme to the wordpress theme engine, the one it loads all the themes available so any update you push to it, will require an update in both sites with just one button.
3. An script that will copy the theme to both sites (not a good option)

Comment: i vote number 2